# Export the data from database to Excel and Sum the Columns?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

I am stuck with a small problem, I am able to export the data from a database to the excel sheet but before saving the newly created excel sheet I want to add the summation formula in my specified columns and I am aware of how to do it with the old excel file which has already been created but don't know how to do it on the new file which is being created during the export process.
  Kindly give me suggestions on how can I achieve my desire task.

Best Regards.

This what I have done so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExportToExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            obj.ExportToExcelMethod();
        }

        public void ExportToExcelMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn;
                string connStr = null;
                string query = null;
                string data = null;
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;

                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                connStr = @"Data Source=GP_DEV\BCDEMO;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
                conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                query = "spGetEmployees";
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Database connection unsuccessful.");
                    System.Environment.Exit(0);
                }

                adpt.Fill(ds);

                for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                    }
                }

                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"D:\khubaib\2-4-20\ExportToExcelFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmmsss") + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();

            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data export unsuccessful.");
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I was using the summation formula.

```
try
            {


                var app = new Excel.Application();
                var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(template);
                var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
                sheet.Cell("C6").Formula = "SUM(C2:C4)";

                workbook.Save();

            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to add the columns.");
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For add summation before save just add 1 line before saving workbook as below

```
// Add this line
xlWorkSheet.Cell("C6").Formula = "SUM(C2:C4)";

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"D:\khubaib\2-4-20\ExportToExcelFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmmsss") + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

You can add more formula or text by using

```
xlWorkSheet.Cell("Desire cell name").Formula = "Formula here"
```

or

```
xlWorkSheet.Cell("Desire cell name").Value = "Text here"
```